# creating NSDate from format

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

What is the NSFormat required for a string like this?

> Fri, 15 Jun 2012 15:37:38 GMT

I'm trying to create a NSDate object from it. thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 15 Jun 2012 15:37:38 GMT"];
NSLog([date description]); //2012-06-15 15:37:38 +0000
```

Comment: not working? I tried putting a comma as well and that didnt work: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"